# Hex to character and print letter by letter

Tags: python

Hello I'm working on a program that would have hex in an array:

```
data = ['000000'] #random dummy hex
```

and I'm trying to decode the hex and print the characters letter from letter as if someone was typing:

```
def typer(type):
s = bytearray.fromhex(type).decode()
for y in type:
 sleep(0.1)
 sys.stdout.write(y)
 sys.stdout.flush()
```

And what's happening is that it will print out the hex number from number instead of converting it to it's string and printing the string letters from letter. But when i put:

```
def typer(type):
s = bytearray.fromhex(type).decode()
for y in type:
 sleep(0.1)
 sys.stdout.write(s)
 sys.stdout.flush()
```

It spams the string instead, but i want it to do letter from letter as if someone was typing, and doesn't stop until it's at the end of the string. I've tried every method from doing those above, to having it decode the hex and print the string in a file then output it and try having it do it, and none of those won't work.

but the total code is:

```
data = ['0000'] #dummy hex
def typer(type):
  s = bytearray.fromhex(type).decode()
  for y in type:
   sleep(0.1)
   sys.stdout.write(y)
   sys.stdout.flush() 

typer(data[0])
```

Comment: What's the point of the `s = ...` line, when you don't use `s` anywhere else in the function?  You should probably be looping over `s` rather than `type`.

Comment: @jasonharper wait it works. Thank you so much

Comment: Remember also `type` is a python reserved word. You’re overwriting the `type` builtin.